# CHAdeMO to Type 2 connector for charging EV cars

Tags: electric-vehicles

I'd like to refresh and potentially update my knowledge.

Is there anything like CHAdeMO charging cable to Type 2 car plug connector? or any other solution that would allow me to charge my Type 2 car from CHAdeMO cable / charging station? Or no such thing exists.

My knowledge gained so far says that there isn't anything like that and that designing such thing isn't possible due to wide differences in CHAdeMO and Type 2 interfaces up to the level of different request-answer timeouts, voltages, logic and software behind.

I understand that CHAdeMO technology / protocol / standard is being phased-out worldwide, but here were I live (Poland) there is a serious number of (roughly ever used) public EV chargers with CHAdeMO cable. And I'd like to have an additional option of charging my Type 2 car with such cable in situation when other solutions (like using Type 2 cable / plug or CCS cable) are not available (had such situation only yesterday twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to various sources, [wiki included, CHAdeMO is a DC resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHAdeMO) of varying voltage depending on version number. Type 2, also known as L2 or Level 2 is an AC power source and your onboard charger is designed to rectify that alternating current into the DC your battery requires. Also part of the L2 specifications is the ability to communicate between the OBC and the EVSE to provide appropriate power levels to the OBC.

The range of power available at some commercial EVSE units can be from 3kW to 10kW. The above wiki suggests that home units can be purchased to provide power of 22kW, but I've not seen that rating. Our home EVSE is a 10kW unit and the OBC of our Rav4EV is rated to 11kW, providing for a good match.

I suspect it's going to be difficult to impossible to locate an adapter to convert high current/high DC voltage to lower current/lower AC voltage along with the negotiation circuitry which would be required to make such a device work safely.

Your third paragraph is supported by information available.

Comment: You can convert anything ( for sufficient definition of "anything") with enough electronics.  Take a look at the physical size of the Tesla  ChadEMo - to Tesla adapter.