# A converter from CHAdeMO cable to CCS connector for charging EV cars

Tags: electric-vehicles

A very similar question to [this one](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/52283/39087). Is there any solution available to use CHAdeMO charging cable to power EV car equipped with CCS socket?

My knowledge gained so far says that there isn't anything like that because there are too wide differences in CHAdeMO and CCS interfaces (up to the level of different request-answer timeouts, voltages, logic, software behind, etc.).

I understand that CHAdeMO technology / protocol / standard is being phased-out worldwide, but here were I live (Poland) there is a vast number of public EV chargers with (roughly never used) CHAdeMO cables.

I'd like to have an additional option of charging my CCS car with CHAdeMO cable in situation when options (Type 2 cable or plug or CCS cable) are not available.

I don't know much of anything about Tesla, but I saw Tesla driver powering its car from CHAdeMO (or maybe it was CSS?) cable using some kind of converter or inverter plugged between EV charging station's cable and Tesla's socket. I'd like to know, if similar option exists, if we have CCS instead of Tesla socket?

Comment: Theoretically possible even with different timeouts, etc as the middleman can first negotiate to get power before negotiating to give power to the vehicle.  Tech for converting voltage has been around longer than electricity has been made a utility... Software and logic turn into physical signals at the interface so usually voltages again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as my comment on the previous question:  you can convert any electrical power source to any desired output format with enough electronics. It's just not worth it given the use-cases.
Yes, Tesla used to sell a ChaDeMo - to -Tesla adapter.   No longer, because:

Frankly, ChaDeMo is dead - nobody is building vehicles designed for that, and no new stations that Iknow of  are being installed with ChaDeMo output.

I wouldn't be surprised if some hobbyist or specialty shop decided to make a ChadeMo to CCS converter "for fun,"  but I rather doubt it's worth the money or the risk to your vehicle to get one.

Comment: So, to summarize, each and every station in Poland (or generally in Europe, the world) that still has CHAdeMO cable is an old one and I may expect it being replaced for Type 2 / CCS only soon or later -- right.

Comment: @trejder my guess is 'yes,'  since to my knowledge no vehicle currently or planned to be in production has a chadeMo input, so there's no user base going forward

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an exactly the same solution / converter as asked is available in the market: **Tesla Chademo Adapter EU 1036391-10-D**. [Here is](https://allegro.pl/oferta/tesla-chademo-adapter-eu-1036391-10-d-11414853743) a link to a Polish shop offer for one of them:

[image]

If I am getting the above picture correctly, this is exactly what I've been asking for: Put a CHAdeMO cable from a charger into this adapter and put the adapter into CCS socket in an electric car.

The price (2499 PLN / 510 USD / 530 EUR) is a killer for me. I'd rather go to the second or third charger, if previous one has only CHAdeMO cable available rather than spending that amount of money for such an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not even shure every car will accept DC over the type2 connector of the CCS socket , since as far as I understand it the type2 part is only for the handshake and the DC goes over the 2 big pins under it. Do you know of any cars accepting Dc over the type2 socket ?

regards bart

autosol@gmx.com

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange. Please, read the guidelines. This is not a forum. Please, don't post answers, if you are unsure. Please, don't add "regards" and don't publish your private email address. No, CCS is a 100% extension of Type 2. Basically CCS = Type 2 + two additional pins. But this question deals with ChaDeMo, so your answer (which actually isn't an answer as per standards of this page) is off-topic, sorry.